# VS 2012 and SelectParameter in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi I want to bind text string in SelectCommand code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:finchsize_polibudaConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT ocena FROM Oceny AS lista WHERE przedmiot = @ID"/>
     <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DefaultValue="0" Name="ID"
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
```

But my VS 2012 said that: 1.Validation(XHTML5): Element SelectParameters is not supported. 2. Element 'ControlParameter' is not a known element. Do yuo know how to fix that, or is it any other way to bind some text in SelectCommand ?

P.S. I tried

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter />
```

as well but it gives me exactly the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectParameters` element needs to be a child of `SqlDataSource`.  Right now you have it as a peer

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:finchsize_polibudaConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT ocena FROM Oceny AS lista WHERE przedmiot = @ID">
     <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DefaultValue="0" Name="ID"
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```